# In XPath how to select the element content

Tags: xpath, element

Is there a way of writing an XPath expression to select the content of the element.

e.g.

```
<Element>xxx</Element>
```

Assuming I can write XPath (/Element) to get `Element` how do I tweak the XPath to get xxxx returned rather than the Element wrapper?

**EDIT/ANSWER**

To do this in dom4j world use the `Element.valueOf(String xpathExpression)` rather than the .selectXXX() methods.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use the `value-of` element:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Some/Path/To/Element"/>
```

If you can only specify an XPath then use the `text` function like this:

> `/Some/Path/To/Element/text()`

Comment: Thanks but I just want an XPath expression.  I'm not using XSLT, just dom4j with jaxen inside Java code.

Comment: Ah, it turns out in dom4j that text() returns a DefaultText element. However I found a function in dom4j called valueOf(XPath xpath) that does exactly what your first example does (String representation of XPath result) so that worked nicely.  Thanks again.

Comment: How can this answer be the accepted and most upvoted one when it doesn't use XPath to extract the content? it answers a different question.

Answer (score 0):

A bit too late but...

```
data(Element)
```

...should also be fine.

Comment: Not for me. I don't know what you're using, but `data` is not a standatd XPath function.