# Get all the substrings between two characters in a file

Tags: java, xml, oop, parsing, file-handling

I have a file which looks like below
￼

```
<title>1 INDICATIONS AND USAGE</title>
    <text>
        <paragraph>Therapy with lipid-altering agents should be only one component of multiple risk factor intervention in individuals at significantly increased risk for atherosclerotic vascular disease due to hypercholesterolemia. Drug therapy is recommended as an adjunct to diet when the response to a diet restricted in saturated fat and cholesterol and other nonpharmacologic measures alone has been inadequate. In patients with CHD or multiple risk factors for CHD, LIPITOR can be started simultaneously with diet.</paragraph>
    </text>
    <effectiveTime value="20170630"/>
    <excerpt>
        <highlight>
            <text>
                <paragraph>LIPITOR is an HMG-CoA reductase inhibitor indicated as an adjunct therapy to diet to:</paragraph>
                <list listType="unordered" styleCode="disc"> <item>Reduce the risk of MI, stroke, revascularization procedures, and angina in adult patients without CHD, but with multiple risk factors (<linkHtml href="#S1.1">1.1</linkHtml>).</item>
                    <item>Reduce the risk of MI and stroke in adult patients with type 2 diabetes without CHD, but with multiple risk factors (<linkHtml href="#S1.1">1.1</linkHtml>).</item>
                    <item>Reduce the risk of non-fatal MI, fatal and non-fatal stroke, revascularization procedures, hospitalization for CHF, and angina in adult patients with CHD (<linkHtml href="#S1.1">1.1</linkHtml>).</item>
                    <item>Reduce elevated total-C, LDL-C, apo B, and TG levels and increase HDL-C in adult patients with primary hyperlipidemia (heterozygous familial and nonfamilial) and mixed dyslipidemia (<linkHtml href="#S1.2">1.2</linkHtml>).</item>
                    <item> Reduce elevated TG in adult patients with hypertriglyceridemia and primary dysbetalipoproteinemia (<linkHtml href="#S1.2">1.2</linkHtml>).</item>
                    <item>Reduce total-C and LDL-C in patients with homozygous familial hypercholesterolemia (HoFH) (<linkHtml href="#S1.2">1.2</linkHtml>).</item>
                    <item>Reduce elevated total-C, LDL-C, and apo B levels in pediatric patients, 10 years to 17 years of age, with heterozygous familial hypercholesterolemia (HeFH) after failing an adequate trial of diet therapy (<linkHtml href="#S1.2">1.2</linkHtml>).</item>
                </list>
                <paragraph><content styleCode="underline">Limitations of Use</content>:</paragraph>
                <paragraph>LIPITOR has not been studied in <content styleCode="italics">Fredrickson </content>Types I and V dyslipidemias (<linkHtml href="#S1.3">1.3</linkHtml>).</paragraph>
            </text>
        </highlight>
    </excerpt>
    <component>
        <section ID="S1.1">
            <id root="3a10e3ca-e81c-43c9-9262-e15f334eedfc"/>
            <code code="42229-5" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="SPL UNCLASSIFIED SECTION"/>
            <title>1.1 Prevention of Cardiovascular Disease in Adults</title>
            <text>
                <paragraph>In adult patients without clinically evident coronary heart disease, but with multiple risk factors for coronary heart disease such as age, smoking, hypertension, low HDL-C, or a family history of early coronary heart disease, LIPITOR is indicated to:</paragraph>
                <list listType="unordered" styleCode="disc">
                    <item>Reduce the risk of myocardial infarction</item>
                    <item>Reduce the risk of stroke</item>
                    <item>Reduce the risk for revascularization procedures and angina</item>
                </list>
                <paragraph>In adult patients with type 2 diabetes, and without clinically evident coronary heart disease, but with multiple risk factors for coronary heart disease such as retinopathy, albuminuria, smoking, or hypertension, LIPITOR is indicated to:</paragraph>
                <list listType="unordered" styleCode="disc"> <item>Reduce the risk of myocardial infarction</item>
                    <item>Reduce the risk of stroke</item>
                </list>
                <paragraph>In adult patients with clinically evident coronary heart disease, LIPITOR is indicated to:</paragraph>
                    <list listType="unordered" styleCode="disc">
                        <item>Reduce the risk of non-fatal myocardial infarction</item>
                        <item>Reduce the risk of fatal and non-fatal stroke</item>
                        <item>Reduce the risk for revascularization procedures</item>
                        <item>Reduce the risk of hospitalization for CHF</item>
                        <item>Reduce the risk of angina</item>
                    </list>
                </text>
            <effectiveTime value="20170630"/>
        </section>
    </component>
    <component> 
        <section ID="S1.2">
            <id root="d9003937-e6d4-453b-a767-40f6077a351a"/>
            <code code="42229-5" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="SPL UNCLASSIFIED SECTION"/>
            <title>1.2 Hyperlipidemia</title>
            <text>
                <paragraph>LIPITOR is indicated:</paragraph>
                <list listType="unordered" styleCode="square"> <item>As an adjunct to diet to reduce elevated total-C, LDL-C, apo B, and TG levels and to increase HDL-C in adult patients with primary hypercholesterolemia (heterozygous familial and nonfamilial) and mixed dyslipidemia (<content styleCode="italics">Fredrickson </content>Types IIa and IIb);</item>
                    <item>As an adjunct to diet for the treatment of adult patients with elevated serum TG levels (<content styleCode="italics">Fredrickson </content>Type IV);</item>
                    <item>For the treatment of adult patients with primary dysbetalipoproteinemia (<content styleCode="italics">Fredrickson </content>Type III) who do not respond adequately to diet;</item>
                    <item>To reduce total-C and LDL-C in patients with homozygous familial hypercholesterolemia (HoFH) as an adjunct to other lipid-lowering treatments (e.g., LDL apheresis) or if such treatments are unavailable;</item>
                    <item>As an adjunct to diet to reduce total-C, LDL-C, and apo B levels in pediatric patients, 10 years to 17 years of age, with heterozygous familial hypercholesterolemia (HeFH) if after an adequate trial of diet therapy the following findings are present:<list listType="ordered" styleCode="LittleAlpha"> <item>LDL-C remains ≥ 190 mg/dL or</item> <item>LDL-C remains ≥ 160 mg/dL and:<list listType="unordered" styleCode="disc"> <item>there is a positive family history of premature cardiovascular disease or</item> <item>two or more other CVD risk factors are present in the pediatric patient</item> </list> </item> </list> </item>
                </list>
            </text>
            <effectiveTime value="20170630"/>
        </section>
    </component>
    <component>
        <section ID="S1.3">
            <id root="b9d715d4-0a9e-4ada-9fd8-574fd627290a"/>
            <code code="42229-5" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" displayName="SPL UNCLASSIFIED SECTION"/>
            <title>1.3 Limitations of Use</title>
                <text>
                    <paragraph>LIPITOR has not been studied in conditions where the major lipoprotein abnormality is elevation of chylomicrons (<content styleCode="italics">Fredrickson </content>Types I and V).</paragraph>
                </text>
                <effectiveTime value="20170630"/>
            </section>
        </component>
    </section>
</component>
<component> 
    <section ID="S2">
        <id root="be8db708-c4d3-4fba-934c-6e372b862de6"/>
        <code code="34068-7"
```

I want to parse the file and get all the text between the tags.

So I have written a code which says get me the substring between '>' and '

How do I get all the tags in the entire file?

**Code**

```
try {
    File file = new File("A:/OneDrive - PharmaCompany, Inc/Diksha Work/usage1.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String line,l;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                                

        int start =(line.indexOf(">"));
        int end=(line.indexOf("</"));                       
        String name = line.substring(start+1,end);
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    fileReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm gettingt just the text text between first two tags:

**Actual output**

> 1 INDICATIONS AND USAGE

**Expected output**

> 1 INDICATIONS AND USAGE Therapy with lipid-altering agents should be
>   only one component of multiple risk factor intervention in individuals
>   at significantly increased risk for atherosclerotic vascular disease
>   due to hypercholesterolemia. Drug therapy is recommended as an adjunct
>   to diet when the response to a diet restricted in saturated fat and
>   cholesterol and other nonpharmacologic measures alone has been
>   inadequate. In patients with CHD or multiple risk factors for CHD,
>   LIPITOR can be started simultaneously with diet. LIPITOR is an HMG-CoA
>   reductase inhibitor indicated as an adjunct therapy to diet to:
>   ... (and so on all the text between the tags till the end of the file)

Comment: Your expected output shows that you want all the text without the tags, so rather than extracting the text, you could just remove the tags. Load entire file into memory, then use regex `s = s.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");`

Comment: Have you thought about using an XML parser?

Comment: you can use Xpath to retreive nodes or content [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2470208/282956)

Comment: @Andreas That was easy! Thank you that helped!

Answer (score 1):

In order to extract all non-zero length text between > and < characters  from the text file, you may use the regexular expression ">([^>|^<]{1,})<".

```
        String text= "fljjl;<xmlelement>value</xmlelement> <jjjj> <tag>kkk< ><'l'l'";
        final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(">([^>|^<]{1,})<").matcher(text);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

for eg , the above code will extract "value" and "kkk" from the text string.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you searh:

String[] String.split(String regex)

and you can take one element on two for example :

```
String a = "aatotoaabbisinthebbaakitchenaa";
String [] output = a.split("aa");
```

output will contains : ["", "toto", "bbisinthebb", "kitchen"]
so the word surround by "aa" are in impaar position in the array. (toto => 1 and kitchen => 3)

if your objectif is to parse xml don't do this! there are some library to do that like JAXB. Eclipse provide all the tool to generate classes from the xsd of your xml this will be far easier to use.

**Edit :**

in your cas you don't search for "aa but some tha match with this kind of patern :

```
(?i)(<(/?)title.*?>)(.+?)()
```

so in the same way juste replace "title" by the balise you are searching in the pattern

Comment: `<title>` != `</title>`

Comment: you can use regex like "(?i)(<title.*?>)(.+?)()"

Comment: such as "(?i)(<(/?)title.*?>)(.+?)()" will be better

Comment: Edit it into your answer then. And what about the different types of tags, `title` isn't the only one. There is also `item` and `paragraph`

Comment: for complexe parsing i am not sur that it's the good method it should use XPath or JAXB and refered to the doc of these api